# Probability distribution, n dice

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose I have $n$ fair dice with 6 faces each (numbers from $1$ to $6$). I define a random variable $X_n$ - sum of numbers on dice after the throw. Is there any probability distribution I can use to calculate exact probabilities for every value of this random variable? I'm interested in a distribution that gives exact values, not something like CLT.